Ошибка: google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: Unable to find the server at oauth2.googleapis.com
Я делаю проект на django. С помощью celery мне надо в определённое время обновлять гугл таблицу, закидывая в неё новые данные из стороннего api. Но как только celery получает задачу, у меня возникает ошибка:
[2024-04-01 14:34:00,336: INFO/MainProcess] Task google_ads.tasks.update_google_spreadsheet[13da8463-27eb-447c-8967-8c385fd79d7b] received
[2024-04-01 14:34:00,339: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function fast_trace_task at 0x000001EF25461F80> (args:('google_ads.tasks.update_google_spreadsheet', '13da8463-27eb-447c-8967-8c385fd79d7b', {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'google_ads.tasks.update_google_spreadsheet', 'id': '13da8463-27eb-447c-8967-8c385fd79d7b', 
'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, None], 'root_id': '13da8463-27eb-447c-8967-8c385fd79d7b', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': '()', 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen16544@LAPTOP-09UDD77E', 'ignore_result': False, 'replaced_task_nesting': 
0, 'stamped_headers': None, 'stamps': {}, 'properties': {'correlation_id': '13da8463-27eb-447c-8967-8c385fd79d7b', 'reply_to': '87fb7af1-8e34-37ad-b7f9-e2fc09b0c815', 'periodic_task_name': 'update-google-spreadsheet-every-night', 'delivery_mode': 2, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}, 'priority': 0, 'body_encoding': 'base64', 'delivery_tag': 'fa0a621b-a10f-404f-9512-33f98cc0a571'}, 'reply_to': '87fb7af1-8e34-37ad-b7f9-e2fc09b0c815', 'correlation_id':... kwargs:{})
[2024-04-01 14:34:00,349: WARNING/MainProcess] 1
[2024-04-01 14:34:00,597: WARNING/MainProcess] 3
[2024-04-01 14:34:00,634: INFO/MainProcess] file_cache is only supported with oauth2client<4.0.0
[2024-04-01 14:34:00,645: WARNING/MainProcess] 4
[2024-04-01 14:34:00,654: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): luck2you.ru:443
[2024-04-01 14:34:01,614: DEBUG/MainProcess] https://luck2you.ru:443 "GET /jl8sn.php?page=Stats&camp_id=55&group1=27&group2=290&date=9&num_page=1&val_page=All&api_key=80000019bdb5f8f0830a2523952418bb6eccb13 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
[2024-04-01 14:34:01,862: WARNING/MainProcess] 7
[2024-04-01 14:34:01,865: WARNING/MainProcess] 5
[2024-04-01 14:34:02,458: DEBUG/MainProcess] URL being requested: POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1IfqgOYPkTNqsh1leF2ftulW5OGeBk0-auF3xT9pL4yA/values:batchUpdate?alt=json
[2024-04-01 14:34:02,528: DEBUG/MainProcess] Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
[2024-04-01 14:34:02,691: ERROR/MainProcess] Task google_ads.tasks.update_google_spreadsheet[13da8463-27eb-447c-8967-8c385fd79d7b] raised unexpected: TransportError(ServerNotFoundError('Unable to find the server at oauth2.googleapis.com'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1366, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1156, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenio\base.py", line 255, in connect
    if socket_connect(fd, address):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenio\base.py", line 39, in socket_connect
    err = descriptor.connect_ex(address)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 119, in __call__
    response, data = self.http.request(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1724, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1444, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1373, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
httplib2.error.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at oauth2.googleapis.com

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 477, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 760, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\google_ads\tasks.py", line 37, in update_google_spreadsheet
    update_spreadsheet_values(service, link, formatted_data)
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\google_ads\utils.py", line 86, in update_spreadsheet_values
    }).execute()
       ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 209, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(self._request, method, uri, request_headers)
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\credentials.py", line 230, in before_request
    self._blocking_refresh(request)
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\credentials.py", line 193, in _blocking_refresh
    self.refresh(request)
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 445, in refresh
    access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 308, in jwt_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 268, in _token_endpoint_request
    response_status_ok, response_data, retryable_error = _token_endpoint_request_no_throw(
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 215, in _token_endpoint_request_no_throw     
    request_succeeded, response_data, retryable_error = _perform_request()
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 191, in _perform_request
    response = request(
               ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jrsyt\OneDrive\Документы\VS_Code\googleAds\env\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 126, in __call__
    raise exceptions.TransportError(exc)
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: Unable to find the server at oauth2.googleapis.com

Вот мой код задачи:
from celery import shared_task
from .utils import fetch_data_from_api, update_spreadsheet_values, filter_data
from .models import Campaign
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import httplib2
import googleapiclient.discovery


CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'genuine-flight-417318-36aacf4a1fc2.json'  # Имя файла с закрытым ключом

@shared_task
def update_google_spreadsheet():
    print(1)
    # Получение данных из БД
    campaigns = Campaign.objects.all()

    for campaign in campaigns:
        camp_id = campaign.campaign_id
        domen = campaign.domen
        link = campaign.spreadsheet_link
        conversion_name = campaign.conversion_name
        api_key = campaign.api_key
        print(3)
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
                                                                                                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
        service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
        print(4)
        # Получение данных из API
        data = fetch_data_from_api(camp_id, api_key)

        if data is not None and data != "no_clicks":
            print(7)
            new_data = filter_data(data, domen)
            formatted_data = [{"name": item['name'], "conversion_name": conversion_name} for item in new_data]
            print(5)
            update_spreadsheet_values(service, link, formatted_data)
            print(6)

        elif data == "no_clicks":
            print(8)
            spreadsheet_id = link.split('/')[-2]
            
            service.spreadsheets().values().clear(
                spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
                range="",
                body={}
            ).execute()
    print(2)

И код функции update_spreadsheet_values:
# Заполнение гугл-таблицы данными
def update_spreadsheet_values(service, link, data):

    # Формируем данные для обновления
    current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S").upper()
    values = [[entry['name'], entry['conversion_name'], current_datetime] for entry in data]
    data_to_update = {
        "range": "A1:C{}".format(len(values)),  
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",  
        "values": values  
    }

    # Выполняем обновление таблицы
    spreadsheet_id = link.split('/')[-2]
    results = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body={
        "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
        "data": [data_to_update]
    }).execute()

    return results

Почему-то, когда я использую эту функцию не через celery, а когда сам запрашиваю данные в первый раз, всё работает прекрасно. Поэтому, непонятно, почему тоже самое через celery не работает.
